# split the multiple lines files into small files based on the content

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh

I want to create a script to split large files into multiple files with respect to line numbers. Mainly if a file is getting split there should be a complete line at the end / beginning.

No partial line should present in any of the split files.

Comment: tried this 1 but didn't work :(                                                                     awk 'NR%100==1{x="abc"++i;}{sed -n '$p' |awk -v RS=="." '{ NR }'}{print > x}}' abc.txt

Answer (score 0):

`split` is what you might be looking for.

```
split --lines <linenumber> <file>
```

and you will get a bunch of splitted files named like: `PREFIXaa, PREFIXab`...

For further info see `man split`.